# EF Core - создание связи многие ко многим

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Подскажите, при использовании принципа Model First как создается отношение многие ко многим. Для примера создал модель с тремя сущностями: A,B,C. Причем А - основная, остальные зависимые. После настройки связи многие ко многим между А-В и А-С в классе сущности А появились поля типа: `public virtual ICollection<В> В { get; set; }` и `public virtual ICollection<С> С { get; set; }`, ну соответственно в классе сущности В: `public virtual ICollection<А> А { get; set; }` - аналогичный в классе сущности С. Есть ли необходимость создавать дополнительный класс, если надо то где? По идее в теории описывается что для реализации данного метода необходимо 3 таблицы, но кажется 3 VS не создает.

Comment: Для реализации одного отношения многие ко многим нужно три таблицы. Для таблиц A и B, например: таблица A, таблица B, таблица связей между А и B. Для случая из топика, соответственно, нужно 5 таблиц - A, B, C + связи A-B, A-C

Comment: Насколько понимаю, это создается все в отдельном классе? Т.е. необходимо создать 2 доп класса для связей?